# Double abstract class inheritance and failed to create sessionFactory (hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, sessionfactory

I'm working on Hibernate and i need two abstract classes. First one, `Product` is the main one and there should be no table on the database named `product`. Second abstract class is `ComPart`(inherited from `Product`) and some computer parts like gpu and cpu are inherited from this class. There should be only one table named `com_part` and both CPUs and GPUs should be in this table(table per hierarchy).

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Product{

    private long pID;
    protected String manufacturer;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getPID() {
        return pID;
    }

    @Column(name = "Manufacturer")
    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

}


// computer part abstract class inherited from Product
@Entity
@Table(name = "com_part")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name="disc",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="manufacturer", column=@Column(name="Manufacturer"))
})
public abstract class ComPart extends Product {

    private String platform;

    @Column(name = "PLATFORM", length = 10)
    public String getPlatform() {
        return platform;
    }
}


// Various computer hardwares inherited from ComPart
@Entity
@Table(name="com_part")
@DiscriminatorValue("CPU")
public class Processor extends comPart {
    private String socketType;
    private String chipset;

    //getters setters...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="com_part")
@DiscriminatorValue("GPU")
public class GraphicsCard extends comPart {
    private double memory;

    //getters setters...
}
```

How can i map all these features? Above code even can't create sessionfactory?! it generates these errors:

```
Failed to create sessionFactory object.java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.bts.core.hb.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:35)
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1424)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1351)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1733)
    at com.bts.core.hb.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:32)
```

Comment: I dont think its the cause of your NPE, but you need to remove the `@Table` annotation on your concrete classes (`Processor`, `GraphicsCard`).

Comment: Also, please include relevant portions from your HibernateUtil, particularly where you are loading the configuration.

Comment: HibernateUtil works smooth with simple(no inheritence) test classes.

Comment: The NPE you show in your stacktrace, is occurring when you are initializing your HibernateUtil.

Comment: sorry, table names for concrete classes are 'com_part', edited. should i remove them?

Comment: Yes, remove them. You do not need to define the `@Table` for the concrete classes since you already defined it on your `Product` entity.